# Determine if a relation is transitive

Tags: code-golf, math, graph-theory, decision-problem

## Challenge description

Let's start with some definitions:

- a **relation** is a set of ordered pairs of elements (in this challenge, we'll be using integers)

For instance, `[(1, 2), (5, 1), (-9, 12), (0, 0), (3, 2)]` is a relation.

- a relation is called **transitive** if for any two pairs of elements `(a, b)` and `(b, c)` in this relation, a pair `(a, c)` is also present,
- `[(1, 2), (2, 4), (6, 5), (1, 4)]` is transitive, because it contains `(1, 2)` and `(2, 4)`, but `(1, 4)` as well,
- `[(7, 8), (9, 10), (15, -5)]` is transitive, because there aren't any two pairs 
  `(a, b)`, `(c, d)` present such that `b` = `c`.
- `[(5, 9), (9, 54), (0, 0)]` is not transitive, because it contains `(5, 9)` and `(9, 54)`, but not `(5, 54)`

Given a list of pairs of integers, determine if a relation is transitive or not.

## Input / output

You will be given a list of pairs of integers in any reasonable format. Consider a relation

`[(1, 6), (9, 1), (6, 5), (0, 0)]`

The following formats are equivalent:

```
[(1, 6), (9, 1), (6, 5), (0, 0)] # list of pairs (2-tuples)
[1, 9, 6, 0], [6, 1, 5, 0] # two lists [x1, x2, ..., xn] [y1, y2, ..., yn]
[[1, 6], [9, 1], [6, 5], [0, 0] # two-dimentional int array
[4, 1, 6, 9, 1, 6, 5, 0, 0] # (n, x1, y1, ..., xn, yn)
[1+6i, 9+i, 6+5i, 0+0i] # list of complex numbers

... many others, whatever best suits golfing purposes
```

Output: a truthy value for a transitive relation, falsy otherwise. You may assume that the input will consist of at least one pair, and that the pairs are unique.

Comment: Does the input have to be a list-like format, or can it be an adjacency--matrix-like format?

Comment: You should have a test case that is only transitive because the pairs are ordered. E.g. `(1,3) (2,1) (3,4) (1,4) (2,4)`. If the pairs weren't ordered, this wouldn't be transitive because `(2,3)` is missing.

Comment: @MartinEnder I think you misinterpreted "ordered pairs". I don't think it means the pairs in an order - I think it means each pair has an order, first then second.

Comment: @isaacg that's what I meant. In other words, my test case is only truthy because the relation isn't implicitly symmetric.

Comment: Should the third test case (`[(7, 8), (9, 10), (15, -5)]`) be **not** transitive?

Comment: @MartinEnder What I'm saying is it's not transitive - `(2, 1)` and `(1, 3)` are present, and `(2, 3)` is not, so it's not transitive. An example of what you're saying would be `(1, 2), (1, 3)`.

Comment: @isaacg oh, completely overlooked that one. You're right, your test case is better.

Comment: @wnnmaw: No. The definition is "a relation `r` is transitive if for any a, b, c in `r` [(a, b) in r and (b, c) in r] => (a, c) in r. Since the left side of the implication is false, the whole expression evaluates to true.

Comment: Can the truthy value depend on the relation? e.g. output the relation for true, output 0 for false?

Comment: @ngenisis: sure, those are considered truthy and falsy

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, 42 bytes

```
f x=and[elem(a,d)x|(a,b)<-x,(c,d)<-x,b==c]
```

Usage example: `f [(1,2), (2,4), (6,5), (1,4)]`-> `True`.

(Outer)loop over all pairs `(a,b)` and (inner)loop over the same pairs, now called `(c,d)` and every time when `b==c` check if `(a,d)`is also an existent pair. Combine the results with logical `and`.

Comment: Most readable answer so far!

Comment: @Lynn Check out the Prolog answer, then ;-)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
7#u2e!l6MX>thl4$XQttY*g<~
```

Input format is a matrix (using `;` as row separator) where each pair of the relation is a column. For example, test cases

```
[(1, 2), (2, 4), (6, 5), (1, 4)]
[(7, 8), (9, 10), (15, -5)]
[(5, 9), (9, 54), (0, 0)]
```

are respectively input as

```
[1 2 6 1; 2 4 5 4]
[7 9 15; 8 10 -5]
[5 9 0; 9 54 0]
```

[Truthy](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=PyAgICAgICAgICUgaWYKJ3RydXRoeScgICUgcHVzaCBzdHJpbmcKfSAgICAgICAgICUgZWxzZQonZmFsc3knICAgJSBwdXNoIHN0cmluZw&input=WzEgMSAxOyAxIDEgMTsgMSAxIDFd) output is a matrix formed by ones. [Falsy](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=PyAgICAgICAgICUgaWYKJ3RydXRoeScgICUgcHVzaCBzdHJpbmcKfSAgICAgICAgICUgZWxzZQonZmFsc3knICAgJSBwdXNoIHN0cmluZw&input=WzEgMSAxOyAxIDEgMTsgMSAwIDFd) is a matrix that contains at least one zero.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NyN1MmUhbDZNWD50aGw0JFhRdHRZKmc8fg&input=WzEgMiA2IDE7IDIgNCA1IDRd)

#### Explanation

The code first reduces the input integers to unique, 1-based integer values. From those values it generates the adjacency matrix; matrix-multiplies it by itself; and converts nonzero values in the result matrix to ones. Finally, it checks that no entry in the latter matrix exceeds that in the adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 4):

### Prolog, 66 bytes

```
t(L):-not((member((A,B),L),member((B,C),L),not(member((A,C),L)))).
```

The relation is *not* transitive if we can find (A,B) and (B,C) such that (A,C) doesn't hold.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>69</s> 67 bytes

```
a=>(g=f=>a.every(f))(([b,c])=>g(([d,e])=>c-d|!g(([d,c])=>b-d|c-e)))
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to an idea by @Cyoce. There were four previous 69-byte formulations:

```
a=>a.every(([b,c])=>a.every(([d,e])=>c-d|a.some(([d,c])=>b==d&c==e)))
a=>!a.some(([b,c])=>!a.some(([d,e])=>c==d&a.every(([d,c])=>b-d|c-e)))
a=>a.every(([b,c])=>a.every(([d,e])=>c-d|!a.every(([d,c])=>b-d|c-e)))
(a,g=f=>a.every(f))=>g(([b,c])=>g(([d,e])=>c-d|!g(([d,c])=>b-d|c-e)))
```

Comment: You might be able to shorten the second solution by making an abbreviation for `.every`

Comment: @Cyoce Indeed, you save 3 bytes each time by writing `[e]`, so even though it costs 8 bytes to assign `e` you still save a byte. However, I went a step further by making an abbreviation for `a.every`, which saved a second byte.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
!-eMfqFhTCM*_M
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21-eMfqFhTCM%2a_M&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5B1%2C+2%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+4%5D%2C+%5B6%2C+5%5D%2C+%5B1%2C+4%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B7%2C+8%5D%2C+%5B9%2C+10%5D%2C+%5B15%2C+-5%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B5%2C+9%5D%2C+%5B9%2C+54%5D%2C+%5B0%2C+0%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C+6%5D%2C+%5B9%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B6%2C+5%5D%2C+%5B0%2C+0%5D%5D&debug=0)

Input format is expected to be `[[0, 0], [0, 1], ... ]`

```
!-eMfqFhTCM*_M
!-eMfqFhTCM*_MQQQ    Variable introduction
            _MQ      Reverse all of the pairs
           *   Q     Cartesian product with all of the pairs
         CM          Transpose. We now have [[A2, B1], [A1, B2]] for each pair
                     [A1, A2], [B1, B2] in the input.
    f                Filter on
       hT            The first element (the middle two values)
     qF              Being equal
  eM                 Take the end of all remaining elements (other two values)
 -              Q    Remove the pairs that are in the input
!                    Negate. True if no transitive pairs were not in the input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 24 bytes

```
'{psc[A:B:B:C],?'e[A:C]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog#@69eXVCcHO1o5QSEzrE69uqpQI5zbO3//9HRhlZGsVbRRlbGQNIQTJoAyVgA)

Explanation:

```
'{psc[A:B:B:C],?'e[A:C]}
'{                     } it is impossible to find
    c                    a flattened
   s                     subset of
  p                      a permutation of the input
     [A:B:B:C]           that has four elements, with the second and third equal
              ,?         and such that the input
                'e       does not contain
                  [A:C]  a list formed of the first and fourth element
```

In other words, if the input contains pairs `[A:B]` and  `[B:C]`, we can permute the input to put `[A:B]` and  `[B:C]` at the start, delete all other elements, and produce a list `[A:B:B:C]`. Then we return truthy from the inner predicate (falsey from the whole program) if `[A:C]` isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

### CJam (22 bytes)

```
{__Wf%m*{z~~=*}%\-e_!}
```

[Online test suite](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q'%2C-%22()%22%22%5B%5D%22er~%5D%0A%0A%7B__Wf%25m*%7Bz~~%3D*%7D%25%5C-e_!%7D%0A%0A%25&input=%5B(1%2C%202)%2C%20(2%2C%204)%2C%20(6%2C%205)%2C%20(1%2C%204)%5D%0A%5B(7%2C%208)%2C%20(9%2C%2010)%2C%20(15%2C%20-5)%5D%0A%5B(5%2C%209)%2C%20(9%2C%2054)%2C%20(0%2C%200)%5D). This is an anonymous block (function) which takes the elements as a two-level array, but the test suite does string manipulation to put the input into a suitable format first.

#### Dissection

```
{         e# Begin a block
  _       e#   Duplicate the argument
  _Wf%    e#   Duplicate again and reverse each pair in this copy
  m*      e#   Cartesian product
  {       e#   Map over arrays of the form [[a b][d c]] where [a b] and [c d]
          e#   are in the relation
    z~~=* e#     b==c ? [a d] : []
  }%
  \-      e#   Remove those transitive pairs which were in the original relation
  e_!     e#   Test that we're only left with empty arrays
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
#/.{x=___,{a_,b_},x,{b_,c_},x}/;#~FreeQ~{a,c}:>0&
```

Pure function which takes a list of pairs. If the input list contains `{a,b}` and `{b,c}` but not `{a,c}` for some `a, b, c`, replaces it with `0`. Truthy is the input list, falsy is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## C++14, 140 bytes

As unnamed lambda returning via reference parameter. Requires its input to be a container of `pair<int,int>`. Taking the boring O(n^3) approach.

```c++
[](auto m,int&r){r=1;for(auto a:m)for(auto b:m)if (a.second==b.first){int i=0;for(auto c:m)i+=a.first==c.first&&b.second==c.second;r*=i>0;}}
```

Ungolfed and usage:

```c++
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

auto f=
[](auto m,int&r){
  r=1;                         //set return flag to true
  for(auto a:m)                //for each element
    for(auto b:m)              //check with second element
      if (a.second==b.first){  //do they chain?
        int i=0;               //flag for local transitivity
        for(auto c:m)          //search for a third element
          i+=a.first==c.first&&b.second==c.second;
        r*=i>0;                //multiply with flag>0, resulting in 0 forever if one was not found
      }
}
;

int main(){
 std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> m={
  {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {6, 5}, {1, 4}
 };

 int r;
 f(m,r);
 std::cout << r << std::endl;
 
 m.emplace_back(3,6);
 f(m,r);
 std::cout << r << std::endl;
 
 m.emplace_back(3,5);
 f(m,r);
 std::cout << r << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>91</s> <s>67</s> 55 bytes

```python
lambda s:all(b-c or(a,d)in s for a,b in s for c,d in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3BCsIwEETvfsUcE9hAUxu1gl@iHpKGYKE2Je3Fr4/ZIgX1NDuzb3em1/KIY53D5ZYH@3TeYj7bYRBOdYhJWPKyHzEjxARLDpvpyK9G5in14yKCuApNqCVBGIJmVW0Z1qQiVKx7Ju5S7v6PakLDeiAYVs3@Gz0STrzit@s7XZqU@aFK1n4o02zlhclv)

-24 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun
-12 bytes thanks to Bubbler

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY3RCsIwDEXf/Yo8JpBBO1d14vyR2oeJDAeuG9uE9etrM0RQn@7NzcnNEOZ77/PYVJf4qLvrrYbpOD07xMVqV1XBKkdnmZTjkCJqPUzU9CMsIBbEhtXSScdhbP2MDVrUDDkxoGHQolmZzJooBiW6FcIRbf6PcoZCdMdgRLXM3@ie4SArqV3rdPqUmR8qZeWbMsXneWLiCw) (and fixed your code by changing `lambda x` to `lambda s`.

Comment: @LeakyNun Oh whoops, that was supid stupid of me. Thanks!

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY3BCsIwEETvfsUcE9hAUxu1gl@iHpKGYKE2Je3Fr4/ZIgX1NDuzb3em1/KIY53D5ZYH@3TeYj7bYRBOdYhJWPKyHzEjxARLDpvpyK9G5in14yKCuApNqCVBGIJmVW0Z1qQiVKx7Ju5S7v6PakLDeiAYVs3@Gz0STrzit@s7XZqU@aFK1n4o02zlhclv "Python 2 – Try It Online") by unpacking at `for`s.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
íâ€øʒθË}€нIKg_
```

Port of [*@isaacg*'s Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100690/52210), so make sure to upvote him/her as well!
Also takes the input as a list of pairs (e.g. `[[1,2],[3,4],...]`).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NrDix41rTm849SkczsOd9cC2Rf2enqnx///Hx1tqGMUqxNtpGMCJM10TIGkIZAdCwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8NrDy961LTm8I5Tk87tONxdC2Rf2FvpnR7/X@d/dHS0oY5RrE60kY4JkDTTMQWShkB2rI5CdLS5jgWQa6ljaAASNdXRNYWIm@pYgsVNQXoMdAxiY2MB).

**Explanation:**

```python
í           # Reverse each pair of the (implicit) input-list
 â          # Get the cartesian product of this list and the (implicit) input-list,
            # creating pairs of pairs
  €         # Map over each pair of pairs:
   ø        #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
            # (we now have a list of [[x1,y2],[y1,x2]] of each pair in the input-list, 
            # including those where [x1,y1]==[x2,y2])
    ʒ       # Filter this list of 2x2 blocks by:
     θ      #  Get the last row: [y1,x2]
      Ë     #  Check if the values in the pair are the same: y1==x2
    }€      # After the filter: map over each remaining 2x2 block:
      н     #  Leave just the first row: [x1,y2]
       IK   # Remove all input-pairs from this list of remaining pairs
         g  # And then check if the length
          _ # is equal to 0 (1 if the list was empty; 0 if not)
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Axiom 103 bytes**

```
c(x)==(for i in x repeat for j in x repeat if i.2=j.1 and ~member?([i.1, j.2],x)then return false;true)
```

ungolfed:

```
c(x)==
  for i in x repeat
    for j in x repeat
       if i.2=j.1 and ~member?([i.1, j.2],x) then return false
  true

                                                                   Type: Void
```

the exercises

```
(2) -> c([[1,2],[2,4],[6,5],[1,4]])
   Compiling function c with type List List PositiveInteger -> Boolean
   (2)  true
                                                                Type: Boolean
(3) -> c([[7,8],[9,10],[15,-5]])
   Compiling function c with type List List Integer -> Boolean
   (3)  true
                                                            Type: Boolean
(4) -> c([[5,9],[9,54],[0,0]])
   Compiling function c with type List List NonNegativeInteger ->
      Boolean
   (4)  false
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
.Am},hdedQfqFtPTsM^Q2
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.Am%7D%2ChdedQfqFtPTsM%5EQ2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5B1%2C+2%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+4%5D%2C+%5B6%2C+5%5D%2C+%5B1%2C+4%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B7%2C+8%5D%2C+%5B9%2C+10%5D%2C+%5B15%2C+-5%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B5%2C+9%5D%2C+%5B9%2C+54%5D%2C+%5B0%2C+0%5D%5D&debug=0).

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, <s>56</s> 53 bytes

Update: Instead of using `:when` I'll just check that for all pairs of `[a b]` `[c d]` either `b != c` or `[a d]` is found from the input set.

```
#(every? not(for[[a b]%[c d]%](=[b nil][c(%[a d])])))
```

Original:

Wow, Clojure for loops are cool :D This checks that the `for` loop does not generate a falsy value, which occurs if `[a d]` is not found from the input set.

```
#(not(some not(for[[a b]%[c d]% :when(= b c)](%[a d]))))
```

This input has to be a set of two-element vectors:

```
(f (set [[1, 2], [2, 4], [6, 5], [1, 4]]))
(f (set [[7, 8], [9, 10], [15, -5]]))
(f (set [[5, 9], [9, 54], [0, 0]]))
```

If input must be list-like then `(%[a d])` has to be replaced by `((set %)[a d])` for extra 6 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Both these solutions are unnamed functions taking a list of ordered pairs as input and returning `True` or `False`.

## Mathematica, 65 bytes

```
SubsetQ[#,If[#2==#3,{#,#4},Nothing]&@@@Join@@@#~Permutations~{2}]&
```

`#~Permutations~{2}]` creates the list of all ordered pairs of ordered pairs from the input, and `Join@@@` converts those to ordered quadruples. Those are then operated upon by the function `If[#2==#3,{#,#4},Nothing]&@@@`, which has a cool property: if the middle two elements are equal, it returns the ordered pair consisting of the first and last numbers; otherwise it returns `Nothing`, a special Mathematica token that automatically disappears from lists. So the result is the set of ordered pairs that needs to be in the input for it to be transitive; `SubsetQ[#,...]` detects that property.

## Mathematica, 70 bytes

```
And@@And@@@Table[Last@i!=#&@@j||#~MemberQ~{#&@@i,Last@j},{i,#},{j,#}]&
```

`Table[...,{i,#},{j,#}]` creates a 2D array indexed by `i` and `j`, which are taken directly from the input (hence are both ordered pairs). The function of those two indices is `Last@i!=#&@@j||#~MemberQ~{#&@@i,Last@j}`, which translates to "either the second element of `i` and the first element of `j` don't match, or else the input contains the ordered pair consisting of the first element of `i` and the last element of `j`". This creates a 2D array of booleans, which `And@@And@@@` flattens into a single boolean.

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 39 chars, 78 bytes

```
{∼∨/{(=/⍵[2 3])∧∼(⊂⍵[1 4])∊w}¨,⍵∘.,w←⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{∼∨/{(=/⍵[2 3])∧∼(⊂⍵[1 4])∊w}¨,⍵∘.,w←⍵}
  f (1 2) (2 4) (6 5) (1 4)
1
  f (7 8) (9 10) (15 ¯5)
1
  f (5 9) (9 54) (0 0)
0
```

one second 'solution' follow goto ways:

```
r←q w;i;j;t;v
r←1⋄i←0⋄k←↑⍴w⋄→3
r←0⋄→0
→0×⍳k<i+←1⋄t←i⊃w⋄j←0
→3×⍳k<j+←1⋄v←j⊃w⋄→4×⍳t[2]≠v[1]⋄→2×⍳∼(⊂t[1]v[2])∊w
```

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp, 121 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(not(loop for(a b)in x thereis(loop for(c d)in x do(if(= b c)(return(not(member`(,a ,d) x :test #'equal))))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RasJAEEXf/YqLUrwDColktQr2WzrJrhhIsulmBZ/y63aTFvW@zZxh7qmaeugfbLzvcfEB0Q1xW@ngUHdYk8yxE@5QCPcwksZCBCnkAZ/CI/JMwNxga2ZAGhynvSmQQIZMRBaYYz2YSlqNiFiOivMXRh0/lm@1TDLallZ5F3Y@PtWoKCVJ3RGvLrh6eJEK9o9Yz/rCM0pUwuDiLXTzj9a1pQvf3Cg2VtLhaSrEau1@btrIfx5Pi2n4BQ)